# Creating Unsubscribe Links

Tags: python, security, web, hash

I want to implement a newsletter service. The users of the service will get weekly emails and at the bottom of each email there will be an "Unsubscribe link". The user will be directly unsubscribed from the service on clicking that link. An approach could be to hash email-ids to generate tokens for each user and these tokens can then be used to create the "unsubscribe link" for that user.

I'm implementing the system in python and I have found the library [isdangerous](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) that provides such a functionality.

Is it safe to generate a token for each user when they register and use that same token for the unsubscribe link for all the newsletters ? If not, how should it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why add the complexity of generating a token derived from user email address via hashing (message authentication in reality, if I understand correctly), if you store that token with the user entry anyway?

You could just generate a random token (upon registration for example), store that for your user, and the unsubscribe link in the email would send the email address and the token as a parameter. Note that this means all such emails will contain the token that can be used to unsubscibe a user, but that's probably ok (don't reuse the token for other purposes though). You can also generate and store a different random token for each email, and store those with some expiry so the number of tokens is limited. The benefit of that would be the limited time an attacker has to gain access to such an unsubscribe token, and also you could tell which exact email made your user unsubscribe.

Also the link should not directly unsubscribe a user, because some email clients might download links when the user opens the email. You should have a confirmation step, and to protect against CSRF, that confirmation should use POST to actually unsubscribe a user (passing the same token).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. Can also suggest some other security aspects that I should consider for this application ?